# Service Container is the same Dependency Injection in symfony?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

In symfony framework service's is the same depedency injection ?

What is the difference beetwen service container as Dependency Injection ?

Comment: Consider getting someone to help you translate your question.  What you posted makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

service container as Dependency Injection is a concept for applications developer. Each langugage paradigm as Java, Python or PHP has a service container (DI for Dependency Injection).

For the framework PHP Symfony it tells that Service Container (or just service). In DI concept you can easily delete the contain. It's a obviousness. Because all DI (Java, Python, etc...) live into a container or just a context.

If you already know language that Java and You want to know how symfony manage DI then I just says :"the service" in symfony is the concept of DI for this framework in PHP language.

You can read this post : [What is Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection)

Answer (score 0):

There's pretty much a direct answer in the [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html):

> The DependencyInjection component implements a PSR-11 compatible
>   service container that allows you to standardize and centralize the
>   way objects are constructed in your application.

Also, take a look at the [Service Container docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could probably quibble with this but:

- Dependency injection is a design pattern that you use when writing classes, in which depended upon objects are injected into the instance using a constructor or setter. It is more a concept that you use when thinking about how to write code, but doesn't do anything by itself.
- A service container is an actual thing that is instantiated and creates objects for use in your application. Use of a SC is a design pattern, but the SC is itself instantiated and does things for your application.
- They are related in that the usefulness of a Service Container is (imo) maximized when it is creating objects that leverage the concept of Dependency Injection.